# Why does my matrix become a vector of vectors?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a table that I'm reading into R (as a data.frame), and then selecting some numeric columns out of that data.frame to make into a matrix. I would expect to get a 2D matrix from this, however this is what I get:

```
full = read.table('complete_dataset.txt', header=T, sep="\t", quote="",row.names=NULL, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> matrix(full[ ,4:11])
     [,1]        
[1,] Numeric,6152
[2,] Numeric,6152
[3,] Numeric,6152
[4,] Numeric,6152
[5,] Numeric,6152
[6,] Numeric,6152
[7,] Numeric,6152
[8,] Numeric,6152
> dim(matrix(full[ ,4:11]))
[1] 8 1
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You likely want `as.matrix()`, not `matrix()` here.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix doesn't become a `vector` of `vectors`. It becomes a `matrix` of `lists` having 8 rows. This happens since you supply a `list` (`data.frame`) that contains 8 elements as the data argument to `matrix()`, which then creates a matrix of the list with a default of 1 column.

You basically did:

```
matrix(list(1:3,2:4,3:5))
     [,1]     
[1,] Integer,3
[2,] Integer,3
[3,] Integer,3
```

as @MrFlick notice in the comments you probably want `as.matrix(full[ ,4:11])`, this will convert your subset, `full[ ,4:11]`, with class `data.frame` into a matrix of atomic elements following R's coercion hierarchy.

Comment: `read.table()` just creates a `data.frame` which is also a `list`. `matrix()`  in order turns this list into a matrix of lists, having each vector being a list in the matrix. You can always try playing around with `class()` and `is.list()`